# Angular get object from array of objects with lodash or underscore

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting, lodash

I want to grab property a: from Array of objects  with lodash or underscore

```
     $scope.testarr = [{
                a: '1',
                b: '2'
            }, {
                a: '1',
                b: '2'
            }, {
                a: '1',
                b: '2'
            }, {
                a: '1',
                b: '2'
            }, {
                a: '1',
                b: '2'
            }];
```

Comment: There is no object `a`. You have property `a` on the objects inside the array. The question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Lodash you can use:

```
 var newarr = _.map($scope.testarr, function(obj) {
            return _.omit(obj, 'b');
        });
```

Output:

```
 newarr  = [{
                a: '1'
            }, {
                a: '1'
            }, {
                a: '1'
            }, {
                a: '1'
            }, {
                a: '1'
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make array that contains objects only with 'a' keys, you can use just map method:

```
_.map($scope.testarr, function(o){
  return {a: o.a};
});
```